# The class 'DateTime' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity

Tags: symfony, datetime

After a `composer update` on my Symfony project, I have this error inside my repository:

```
class UserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository implements PasswordUpgraderInterface
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
    }

    public function countOnlineUsers(): int
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('count(u) as userOnline')
            ->where('u.lastSeenDate >= :time')
            ->setParameter('time', (new \DateTime())->modify('-15 minutes'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleScalarResult()
        ;
    }
```

I use `new \DateTime()` on different place of the project and I don't have this error on other place.

[image]

Comment: did you tried `composer dump-autoload`? And try to search in code, possible you using just `new DateTime()` somewhere in entity.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ORM problem fixed here:
https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/8373

Issue: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/8369